# how to disable already selected item in bottombar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

### menu_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
    android:id="@+id/checkin_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nearby"
    android:title="CheckIn"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/message_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
    android:title="Message"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/friends_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_friends"
    android:title="Friend"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/notification_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
    android:title="Notification"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

### Activiy

```
    bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(findViewById(R.id.navigation_view), savedInstanceState);

    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.checkin_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.message_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Favorite Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.friends_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.notification_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    bottomBar.setSelected(false);
                    bottomBar.clearFocus();
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.checkin_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.message_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Favorite Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.friends_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.notification_item:
                    Snackbar.make(drawerLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    bottomBar.setSelected(false);
                    bottomBar.clearFocus();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

### Problem

Bottombar is coming already selected first item. I want to disable this. So when application runs nothing is selected.

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/README.md#common-problems-and-solutions

This bottombar is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now you got to do any of the below two workarounds, I guess.

1) Choose Some other Default Tab using:

```
bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(someIndexOfYOurChoiceFromMenuItems);
```

For eg: you can set

```
bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(1);
```

to select by default Second Item from Tabs:

```
<item android:id="@+id/message_item"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
android:title="Message"
android:orderInCategory="100"
app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

2) Add a dummy Menu Item for a Tab which stays invisible

Add:

```
<item android:id="@+id/none"
android:title=""/>
```

before other Items. This makes it the first Item which gets selected by default.

Comment: It works but uses high memory. why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943655/android-bottom-bar-setting-default-tab-on-create-of-an-activity

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity's `Oncreate`:

```
bottom_navigation_bar.setOnTabSelectListener(this);
bottom_navigation_bar.setOnTabReselectListener(this);
```

then:

```
public void onTabSelected(@idres int tabId) {
    if (bottom_navigation_bar.getRootView().findViewById(tabId).isPressed()){
        switch (tabId) {
            case R.id.tab_home:
                break;
            case R.id.something:
                break;
            case R.id.something:
                break;
            case R.id.something:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and put first tab on `onTabReSelectedmethod`:

```
@override
    public void onTabReSelected(int tabId) {
        switch (tabId) {
            case R.id.tab_home:
                break;
    }
}
```