# android bottom bar setting default tab on create of an activity

Tags: android

Myself trying to develop a sample android app based on [this tutorial](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/) with bottom bar.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.thirdactivity);

        BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
                 Intent myAct = new Intent();
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.item1:
                    myAct = new Intent(findViewById(itemId).getContext(), mainactivity.class);
                    break;
                case R.id.item2:
                    myAct = new Intent(findViewById(itemId).getContext(), secondactivity.class);
                    break;
                case R.id.item3:
                    myAct = new Intent(findViewById(itemId).getContext(), thirdactivity.class);
                    break;
            }
               startActivity(myAct);
            }
        });
    }
```

But how can i set the third tab as default oncreate the activity. The above code highlights the first tab as selected and no even listened when clicking on first tab. Also later tabs opens the respective activities but not highlights as current tab.

**EDIT:** Myself can use  `bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(desiredTabId);` and it working but it uses high memory. What is the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by having `startActivity()` as,

```
 BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);

      bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
                    Intent act = new Intent();
                    if (R.id.item1 == itemId) {
                        act = new Intent(findViewById(itemId).getContext(), act1.class);
                        startActivity(act);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_translate, R.anim.close_scale);
                    }
                    if (R.id.item2 == itemId) {
                        act = new Intent(findViewById(itemId).getContext(), act2.class);
                    }
                    if (R.id.item3 == itemId) {
                        act = new Intent(findViewById(itemId).getContext(), act3.class);
                        startActivity(act);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_translate, R.anim.close_scale);
                    }

                }

            });
            bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(2);

            bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#F3C030");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default tab before your set the listener

```
bottomBar.setDefaultTab(R.id.tab_default);
bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(this);
```

This applies for version 2.0.2

If you set the listener before the default tab, it will be called twice.
Once for tab position 0 and then for anything you set as default, which is usually not desired.

Would be nice to set the default tab before the the creation of bottombar, or a warning in the readme.